# Performance difference between using bind vs. just passing 'this'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am about to run some jsPerf tests targetting the difference between

```
    function Pool(){


    }

    function internal(data){   //private function


    }

    Pool.prototype.run = function(data){   // public function

       return internal.bind(this)(data);

    }

    module.exports = Pool;
```

compared with avoiding the bind call, and just passing 'this' to the private function:

```
function Pool(){


}

function internal(pool, data){   //private function


}

Pool.prototype.run = function(data){   // public function

   return internal(this, data);

}

module.exports = Pool;
```

I imagine it is more performant to use the latter pattern, are there any theoretical cases where it might be less performant? The jsPerf tests might tell me which/what but not why. Also, if you know the names of either of these patterns please let me know, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `internal.call(this, data)`?

Comment: Please also show your jsperf results.

Comment: What do you mean  by `private function`? All your functions are in `global` scope here.

Comment: `.bind()` creates a new function and then calls it and when calling that new function, it then uses `.apply()` or `.call()` to call the original.  So, there's lots of extra stuff going on here with the `.bind()` scheme.  But, you'd have to test to see how much difference it makes.  FYI, you're skipping the more obvious scheme which is `return internal.call(this, data);`.  That should at least be more efficient than `.bind()`.

Comment: @loadaverage sorry, this mostly refers to Node.js, but also you can imagine these calls inside a RequireJS module also

Comment: @AlexMills oh, got it now :)

Comment: I am going to test this, but I really don't see any problem with just passing 'this' directly to a function, it's not really that cumbersome at all, assuming that is the most performant thing to do

Comment: I added my answer, feel free to critique the results

Answer (score 0):

Well, jsPerf doesn't really do it for me, and since Node.js has access to higher resolution timekeeping, I thought I would just run my own test.

So we have two files to be tested:

//one.js

```
function Pool(){

}

function internal(data){
    return this['x'] = data;
}


Pool.prototype.init = function(data){
    return internal.bind(this)(data);
};

module.exports = Pool;
```

//two.js

```
function Pool(){


}

function internal(pool,data){
    return pool['x'] = data;
}


Pool.prototype.init = function(data){
    return internal(this,data);
};

module.exports = Pool;
```

then we test file one.js like so:

```
const Pool = require('./one');


var time = process.hrtime();


for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

   var x =  new Pool().init(String(i) + 'yeah');

}

var diff = process.hrtime(time);

console.log('benchmark took %d nanoseconds', diff[0] * 1e9 + diff[1]);
```

and we test file two.js like so:

```
const Pool = require('./two');


var time = process.hrtime();


for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

    var x = new Pool().init(String(i) + 'yeah');

}


var diff = process.hrtime(time);

console.log('benchmark took %d nanoseconds', diff[0] * 1e9 + diff[1]);
```

I lifted the benchmark code from https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime

accordingly, running test one takes

```
3091851 nanoseconds
```

and running test two takes

```
802445 nanoseconds
```

so passing this directly appears faster, but by how much really?

the difference is

```
2289406 nanoseconds
```

so that's only 2.28 milliseconds difference, which doesn't appear to be much to be concerned about.

However, all in all, without using bind, we see that avoiding bind results in code that is almost `4x` faster, since `3091851/802445 = 3.85`

so without bind, your code runs `~3.85` times faster, but both are quite fast (obviously) so unless you are writing a framework, probably no big deal.

Comment: You are comparing a function call with function creation + function call. What's the point of binding a function if you're not reusing it?

Comment: @destoryer homeboy, you are reusing the private function for different instances of the class.